# Load layout element based on view in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, element

I have a sidebar defined in my main layout which most of the time will display the login form. After the user is logged in I need to remove that form and replace it with user data. I also need to change that sidebar when viewing the support section to show the sub-sections.

Do I need to move the element loading to each view or is there another way?

Thanks in advance,
Denis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bottom line is you're gonna need an `if($supportpage){} elseif($loggedin){} else{}` block. If you don't want to put it in your layout file you could create an element for each option and then `set()` the correct one from the `app_controller`:

```
if ($supportpage) $sidebar = 'support';
elseif ($loggedin) $sidebar = 'loggedin';
else $sidebar = 'notloggedin';

$this->set(compact($sidebar));
```

And then put `$this->element($sidebar)` in your layout.

Comment: Hi ori. Nice ideea with the AppController. I will certanly give it a try. I like to keep the html as clean as possible that is a reason why I choose to use elements in the first place.